# Clone an object introducing a new key-value pair if key with 'chart' is found - JS

Tags: javascript, object

I have a JS object

```
const data = {
  names: {
    chart1: 'arun'
  },
  city: 'New York',
  zip: {
    chart1: 11201
  }
}
```

When I clone, I want to add a new key called chart2 (or incremental) whenever a key with a name 'chart' is found. Please advice.

This is what I did:

```
const newData = {
  names: {
    ...data.names,
    chart2: 'arun'
  },
  city: 'New York',
  zip: {
    ...data.zip,
    chart2: 11201
  }
}
```

But, I want to handle it in a function.

Expected output:

```
{
  city: "New York",
  names: {
    chart1: "arun",
    chart2: "arun"
  },
  zip: {
    chart1: 11201,
    chart2: 11201
  }
}
```

Please advice. The key should be incremental based on the largest value of the chart found. If I clone the above object, the new key should be chart3.

Comment: Please show any attempt that you have made to solve this issue yourself.  You are expected to have made an attempt that we can then help you debug.  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users  Also review [ask]

Comment: If you want to handle it in a function, show us an attempt that you made to do it as such

Comment: Why not use an array of charts? Also, values of every `chart-x` keys will be the same?

Comment: @adiga Yes, the object is created with chart1 by default

Comment: "Incremental" keys are a bad decision. Arrays, arrays, arrays.

Comment: @trincot I have a tab layout similar to https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/ and I store each tab content inside a chart key. I have already written my code and able to access that particular tab data using data['chart1]

Comment: Could just as easily be written to access it as `data.names[0]` as well.

Comment: @Taplar The key here is 'chart'. The new keys should only be added if a key with name 'chart' is found. In case of city, we do not need to clone

Comment: @a2441918, I don't think you understand our point: I repeat: arrays. Did I say arrays? Don't name keys "chart1", "chart2", ... that is bad design. There is no good reason to name them like that. Use arrays.

Comment: I also think its confusing if you are just updating the local keys. Also how do you deal with strings vs numbers because I see both. I will also repeat what everyone else said with arrays, but if you HAVE to use objects I think it would be helpful to understand the context of why you want to do this.

Comment: names: {
    chart1: {data:[1,2,3,4,5], a:1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
  }, this is a similar structure I have in my actual code, how will I use an array in this context?

Answer (score 0):

this code should work :

```
const newData = {
  names: {
    ...data.names,
    [`chart${Object.keys(data.names).length+1}`]: 'arun'
  },
  city: 'New York',
  zip: {
    ...data.zip,
    [`chart${Object.keys(data.zip).length+1}`]: 11201
  }
}
```